# cross compiling python native C extensions with distutilscross, setup.py won't accept '-x' argument

Tags: python, linux, i2c, cross-compiling, python-extensions

I have a working cross compile of Python, however I've tried cross compiling the py-smbus extension from i2c-tools using distutilscross and can't get past the command line.

The documentation (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distutilscross) suggests that it should be as easy as `python setup.py build -x` (after setting appropriate environment variables), however when I run that command the '-x' triggers a bad-argument error.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?  I'm running into the exact same problem and trying to using distutilscross with no success.

Comment: I think this has remained a mystery, I think in the end I gave up end and wrote my own C shim for it. Sorry!

Comment: First I ended up just pulling all the CFLAGS stuff out of the main Makefile for the x-compiled Python, but there's also info in [here](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html#compilation-and-linkage)  on how to include you modules directly in the main compilation of Python which is probably better long-term for my purposes.

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of this approach worked for me:

```
export CC=your-platform-triple-gcc
export LDSHARED="your-platform-triple-ld -shared"
python setup.py build
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the setup.py file uses distutils instead of setuptools.  If you look in the comments of Chris' post, he has a quick fix for this problem:

```
python -c "import setuptools; execfile('setup.py')" -x build
```

http://whatschrisdoing.com/blog/2009/10/16/cross-compiling-python-extensions/